# On proving that $(x_1 x_2 ... x_{r-1} x_r)= (x_2 ... x_{r-1} x_r x_1)=(x_3... x_{r-1} x_r x_1 x_2 )...$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

Let $(x_1x_2...x_{r-1}x_r)$ be a cycle of $S_n$.

Show that $(x_1 x_2 ... x_{r-1} x_r)= (x_2 ... x_{r-1} x_r x_1)=(x_3... x_{r-1} x_r x_1 x_2 )...$

Basically, we can translate the cycle, and it remains the same.

This result is evident, so the question here is of a different nature. How much do I have to write to be considered a mathematical proof?

For example, I can say that, in the first case, $x_1$ goes to $x_2$, $x_2$ goes to $x_1$, and so on, untill $x_r$ goes to $x_1$. The second, $x_2$ goes to $x_3$ ... and $x_r$ goes to $x_1$, so the cycles are equal.

Is this a "proof"? This seems informal to me, I, however, don't know how to formalize a proof for something like this.

Comment: The answer depends on the context - who's the reader, or what's expected in a course where it appears.

Comment: I think the same way. I don't know, I have the feeling that in my college, there is a need for formalization even for results that are 'evident.' Of course, '1+1' may seem evident in one context and not in another, but I feel that even when the goal is just to observe a result, the proof becomes more complicated than the result without necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a proof?

To me, eh. You get the idea. Someone with experience could reconstruct something more rigorous from the idea you get across.

---

Let $\sigma=(x_1\dots x_r)$, $x\in\overline{1,n}$. Then, by definition,

$$\sigma(x)=\begin{cases}
x &: x\notin\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}\\
x_2&: x=x_1\\
\vdots& \,\\
x_r&: x=x_{r-1}\\
x_1&: x=x_r.
\end{cases}$$

But this is independent of the order of the cases; hence:

$$\sigma(x)=\begin{cases}
x &: x\notin\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}\\
x_1&: x=x_r \\
x_2&: x=x_1\\
\vdots& \,\\
x_r&: x=x_{r-1}.\\
\end{cases}$$

Thus $\sigma=(x_rx_1\dots x_{r-1})$.

Then proceed by induction.

---

That's how I would prove it.

But proofs depend on starting definitions, the experience levels of the authors and audience, and the amount of assumed knowledge. Proofs *convince*.

For instance:

- I assumed you're familiar with the notation of cases.
- I assumed you would be comfortable with the easy, inductive step.
- The definition I used is implicit.
- My audience is assumed to be a first or second year undergraduate STEM student.

But think of $1+1=2$. Russell and Whitehead took around 350 pages to prove it from a certain set of axioms, yet with Peano Arithmetic, it's *somewhat* quicker to prove!

Comment: I understand. The way I wrote it seems more like an idea for a demonstration. A strange phenomenon occurs with me: when the theorem is 'evident,' it seems that proving it with formalism becomes more challenging than when the result is not evident. I was having difficulty writing in that way, and your feedback helped a lot. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it can be strange like that sometimes. Please don't forget to accept this answer, if you see fit to, @EmanuelDias.